# Iterating over progressively larger slices from start of list in python

Tags: python, list

Consider the following code that prints the first `n` elements of a list, from `n = 1..N`

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]

for n in range(1, len(lst)+1):
    print(lst[:n])

>>> [1]
>>> [1, 2]
>>> [1, 2, 3]
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I'm looking for a `foreach`-style version of this code to avoid the slightly confusing `range(1, len(lst)+1)`. Something like

```
for sublist in ___(lst):
    print(sublist)
```

I'm sure there is a nice way to do this with `itertools` or something but I can't find anything.

Comment: You could possibly replace `range(1, len(lst)+1)` with `range(len(lst))` and `l[:n]` with `lst[:n+1]`. Otherwise, this is as clean as it gets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to get used to the looks of range() in python if you're going to manipulate indexes and subscripts (which is generally not very pythonic).

Most of the time there is a way to process lists without running through indexes.

This is not a very good example but it illustrates the kind of approach that can be taken:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
def subLists(arr):
    if not arr: return
    for sl in subLists(arr[:-1]): yield sl
    yield arr
```

output:

```
for sublist in subLists(lst): 
    print(sublist)

[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Alternatively, you can avoid the cryptic range(len(lst)) by using enumerate:

```
for n,_ in enumerate(lst,1):
    print(lst[:n])
```

You could also use accumulate from itertools:

```
from itertools import accumulate
for s in accumulate([i] for i in lst):
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a nice one in your desired form. Your way is already good. One alternative I can think of is building them by appending one item at a time.

```
prefix = []
for x in lst:
    prefix.append(x)
    print(prefix)
```